# How do you inherit from CObject and compile successfully?

Tags: mfc, inheritance

I am trying to inherit CObject but am failing to do so.
My class looks like this:

```
class CCanMessage : public CObject
{
public:
    CCanMessage(void);
    ~CCanMessage(void);

    unsigned int m_id; //can-id
    CANMessageTypes m_msgType; //this is an enum 
    unsigned char m_len;
    char *m_pCmdStr;            
};
```

The constructor and destructor are empty.

When I compile I get `error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'`. I have been looking for an explanation for some time now without finding one. I assume the error is embarrassingly simple, but I just can't seem to find it.

Worth noting is that if I don't use the CCanMessage class anywhere the compilation error disappears. The error points to the declaration of the class and not to any place I use the class.

Comment: Also show us your constructor's actual code.  The above code compiles fine under VS2008 with a blank constructor and destructor.

Comment: As I wrote it compiles fine if you don't use it anywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume your issue is with this part from CObject (afx.h):

```
private:
CObject(const CObject& objectSrc);              // no implementation
void operator=(const CObject& objectSrc);       // no implementation
```

Try to provide implementations for the copy constructor and assignment operator for your CCanMessage.

Comment: Just found this out on my own too! Thanks for taking your time.